# Expected to find an object with property ['xyz'] in path $ but found 'org.json.JSONObject'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider:

Tags: java, jsonpath

I am using `json-path` com.jayway.jsonpath:2.4.0`

**Java code:**

```
 public static void main( String[] args )
{
       
    JSONObject jObject =new JSONObject("{\r\n  \"structure\": {\r\n    \"tables\": {\r\n      \"category\": \"vehicle\"\r\n    }\r\n  },\r\n  \"data\": {}\r\n}") ;
    Object jsonPathArray = JsonPath.read(jObject,"$.structure.tables");
 
    System.out.println(jsonPathArray);
}
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Expected to find an object with property ['structure'] in path $ but found 'org.json.JSONObject'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.PropertyPathToken.evaluate(PropertyPathToken.java:71)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.RootPathToken.evaluate(RootPathToken.java:62)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:53)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:61)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:187)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.read(JsonContext.java:102)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.read(JsonContext.java:89)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:488)
    at rxjava.testapp.App.main(App.java:21)
```

how to solve the above exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this by configuring `JsonPath` to use `JsonOrgJsonProvider` provider because by default it uses `JsonSmartJsonProvider` so when you pass `JSONObject` to this method it cannot traverse the object structure :

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject("{\r\n  \"structure\": {\r\n    \"tables\": {\r\n      \"category\": \"vehicle\"\r\n    }\r\n  },\r\n  \"data\": {}\r\n}") ;
        
    Configuration configuration = Configuration.builder()
            .jsonProvider(new JsonOrgJsonProvider())
            .build();

    JsonPath jsonPath = JsonPath.compile("$.structure.tables");
    Object jsonPathArray= jsonPath.read(jObject, configuration);

    System.out.println(jsonPathArray);
}
```

or by passing a `String` directly :

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject("{\r\n  \"structure\": {\r\n    \"tables\": {\r\n      \"category\": \"vehicle\"\r\n    }\r\n  },\r\n  \"data\": {}\r\n}") ;

    Object jsonPathArray= JsonPath.read(jObject.toString(),"$.structure.tables");

    System.out.println(jsonPathArray);
}
```

Output in both cases :

```
{category=vehicle}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply used `JacksonJsonProvider` to solve this as Jackson is a well-developed library that understands the object structure and hierarchy.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

     JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject("{\r\n  \"structure\": {\r\n    \"tables\": {\r\n      \"category\": \"vehicle\"\r\n    }\r\n  },\r\n  \"data\": {}\r\n}") ;
    
     Configuration configuration = Configuration.builder()
             .jsonProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider())
             .build();

     DocumentContext jsonContext = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(jObject.toString());
     Object jsonPathArray= jsonContext.read("$.structure.tables");
     System.out.println(jsonPathArray);
}
```

In case of `Java Object` as input in place of `JSONObject`,use an `ObjectMapper` to use the same function as above.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonData = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
Configuration conf = Configuration.builder()
            .jsonProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider())
            .build();
DocumentContext jsonContext = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(jObject.toString());
```